# My domain name's DNS records are propagating very slowly. Who is to blame?

Tags: domain-name-system

I set the name server records of my domain name around 48 hours back, and the domain name is still not getting propagated. I checked on

https://www.whatsmydns.net/

and I could see that only around 2-3 of the 20 odd DNS servers shown on the map there were returning proper domain records as set by me. So the records are getting updated only partially.

I was wondering who is to blame for this slow propagation, the folks from whom I purchased my domain name, or is it generally that the caches are still not refreshed.

I have several domain names, and the typical time taken for this 4-5 hours; this is the first time that it's taking so long for the DNS updation.

Comment: It's too bad that you didn't include the actual domain name so that we could provide answers. As it is your question will probably be closed because it isn't answerable.

Answer (score 3):

You problem here is that those NS's are not returning your dns records. Make sure that you have dns zone with relevant RR records active on NS49.DOMAINCONTROL.COM/NS50.DOMAINCONTROL.COM

As for how fast your registrar would update NS's on root servers, that depends on where are you changing NS's. Do you send ticket to your registrar or do you change them directly on their interface. You can check whois service of your choice after you change NS's to see if change took place immediately or if there is delay.

Comment: I changed the name servers myself. A query though, if the name servers are not returning any records, how come the records are getting updated partially worldwide?

Comment: @Najeeb https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/aaishazkitchen.com is returning no records, anywhere worldwide. Maybe you had it working and then broke it later on?

Comment: @ceejayoz, the nameserver records are gettingreturned though only partially: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/aaishazkitchen.com.

Comment: @Najeeb you didn't create dns zone with records you need. Those servers that are being used for dns queries are returning RR of your choice (ns, a, cname..) but without active dns zone for your domain, they can't show anything.

Comment: @RonanW. so this dns zone has to be created at the domaincontrol.com server?

Comment: Correct, right now you've set NameServers and they should hold your DNS zone. If you have hosting somewhere, you should have IP address of your hosting server. Log to your account connected to your NS's, create DNS zone, add or use existing records to point them to your hosting server and after a while, you'll get response when doing dns queries.